# composer json, Could not find a version of package

Tags: composer

Пытаюсь сделать установку модуля с помощью composer.

Но при установке получаю ошибку
`Could not find a version of package vatcompliance/vatcompliance matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.`

composer json файл

```
{
  "name": "vatcompliance/vatcompliance",
  "description": "vatcompliance php api library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "OSL-3.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Denys Maksiura",
      "email": "denmaksiura@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6"
  }
}
```

ссылка на пакет
https://packagist.org/packages/vatcompliance/vatcompliance

Почему он не может найти версию или где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: This package is not installable via Composer 1.x, please make sure you upgrade to Composer 2+. Read more about our Composer 1.x deprecation policy.

Comment: но это никак не влияет на мою проблему